# Django URL not working

Tags: python, django

Going to localhost/app works, but localhost/app/upload does not. Am I doing something really obviously wrong? I've tried a few different methods following the documentation without luck. I get a 404 saying the URL pattern does not match.

/project/app/urls.py

```
from app import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.view, name='result'),
    url(r'^upload/$', views.upload, name='upload'),

)
```

/project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^app/$', include('app.urls')),

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't terminate the inclusion URL.

```
url(r'^app/', include('app.urls')),
```